# Upgrading from android 2.2 to Honeycomb

Tags: android

I have worked on android mobile app development, now I want to develop apps for tablets. My current android setup is 2.2, can I upgrade to android Honeycomb. I upgraded from 2.2 to 3.0. But its not honeycomb right?. Am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 3.0 **is** Honeycomb.

If you're looking for a skin, though, try downloading Motorola XOOM add-on for the SDK, which will allow you to create a XOOM Android emulator:
[Motorola XOOM add-on](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Installing_the_Motorola_SDK_Add-on/)